# Array Push Inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to push another array inside array.

This is my array. I want to push another array on **textTabs** .

```
Array
(
    [recipients] => Array
        (
            [signers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [email] => rm@gmail.com
                            [tabs] => Array
                                (
                                    [checkboxTabs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [tabLabel] => sampleCheckbox
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [textTabs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [tabLabel] => CompanyName
                                                    [value] => Qwerty
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [tabLabel] => TradingName
                                                    [value] => Qwerty
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [tabLabel] => ContactName
                                                    [value] => RM
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is my array that i want to add:

```
$array2 = array(
               "tabLabel"=>"MonthlyTotal",
                "value"=>$monthlytotal
          );
```

And this is my php code:

```
$data = array_push($array1['recipients']['signers']['0']['tabs']['textTabs'], $array2);
```

But I was not able to push it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of assignment of `array_push()` to `$data`,as child-array pushed to initial array itself. Just do:

```
array_push($array1['recipients']['signers']['0']['tabs']['textTabs'], $array2);
print_r($array1);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/sntUP

I always prefer doing assignment like below:

```
$array1['recipients']['signers']['0']['tabs']['textTabs'][] = $array2;
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/nHHUB

Answer (score 1):

If you do love a portable way to do add an array or any other values to any key, you may do it using **recursive** function. Let's see an example below:

```
<?php

$old_array = [
    'one' => 'value for one',
    'two' => 'value for two',
    'three' => [
        'four' => 'value for four',
        'five' => 'value for five',
        'six' => [
            'seven' => 'value for seven',
            'eight' => 'value for eight',
        ],
    ],

];

function addArrayToKey($array, $callback){
    $result = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result[$key] = addArrayToKey($value, $callback);
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $callback($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


function callback($key, $value) {
    if('seven' == $key) {
        return ['one', 'two', 'three' => ['four', 'five']];
    }

    return $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(addArrayToKey($old_array, 'callback'));
```